# how to place image logo before text using content attribute in style tag?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML,
i am trying to place image before hello html but nothing will show. I tried below code

````
<head>
<style>
.img::before{
content:url("img\smartphone.png");}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="img">hello html</h1><br>
<h1>hello html</h1><br>
<h1>hello html</h1><br>
<h1>hello html</h1><br>
</body>```
````

Comment: I've create a fiddle with your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ndjgtpkb/) probably you have an error on your url for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link to the image file, you must put a `/`instead of a `\`

````
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .img::before{
            content:url("img/smartphone.png");}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="img">hello html</h1><br>
        <h1>hello html</h1><br>
        <h1>hello html</h1><br>
        <h1>hello html</h1><br>
    </body>
</html>```
````